# Validating a date column in a dataframe in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hbase

I'm reading data from hbase using spark and I have date column in the dataframe and few of the data fields has been corrupted.something like 10-20176-7 etc. How can I check those and replace it with some default values before I process further.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far? Give us some code to start with...

Comment: you can  check existing answer to [verify date](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40510441/647053) and then you can replace invalid dates with default value.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram, I implemented the above logic and getting zero records  in the dataframe though i have records with valid date.

Comment: Might be your logic is wrong. Tzac already asked code snippet where is it ?

Comment: pls Find below for code i'm using. 

val spdfsdate_validate = spdf2.filter(validateDfsdate(_))
val DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD"

  def validateDfsdate(row: Row): Boolean = try {

    val a = java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(row.getString(40), java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT))
   
    true
    
  } catch {
    case ex: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException => {

      false
    }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stack traced the error and below is the error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: 
Text '20140218' could not be parsed: 
Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 
{},ISO resolved to 2014-02-18 of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1918)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1853)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

So I used LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime to resolve the issue. Below is the sample code Used.

```
def validateDfsdate(row: Row): Boolean = try {

val a = java.time.LocalDate.parse(row.getString(40), java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT))

true

} catch {
case ex: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException => {
  println("Exception : " + ex)
  false
}
```

}