# Does the Spark DataFrame writer for CosmosDB take care of empty rows?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm building a large DataFrame after data manipulation, and am writing it back to a CosmosDB collection using the Spark SQL connectors for CosmosDB, using `df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).cosmosDB(writeConfig)`

The class that writes is `DataFrameWriter` from `spark_sql_2.11`. Does the DataFrameWriter check if the row it's about to write only consists of empty strings? If it doesn't, then I would need to verify the rows are not empty before I pass it to the DataFrameWriter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure, just write a map function and filter out all the empty rows, e.g. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306486/spark-dataframe-select-rows-with-at-least-one-null-or-blank-in-any-column-of-tha?rq=1).

Also, does your dataframe contain an id column or do you let CosmosDB generate it for you? If the former is the case, you might run into an error anyway, if the id is an empty string.